What is the best idiomatic way to use .filter() in .agg()?
There are certain contexts in Polars that call on a column, not the entire dataframe, like agg, groupby, with_columns, select, and more.  In these contexts filter sometimes needs to be used.  What is the idiomatic way to use filter in this situation?
E.g.:
import polars as pl
from polars import col

confidence_level = 0.95
lookback_days = 200

percentile_lower = col.Excess_Return.quantile(quantile=1-confidence_level)
percentile_upper = col.Excess_Return.quantile(quantile=confidence_level)

rachev_ratio = excess_return.with_row_index().rolling('index', period=str(lookback_days)+'i').agg(
    Date = col.Date.last(),
    Price = col.Price.last(),
    PnL = col.PnL.last(),
    TBill_Return = col.TBill_Return.last(),
    Excess_Return = col.Excess_Return.last(),
    Percentile_Lower = percentile_lower,
    Percentile_Upper = percentile_upper,
    Lower_CVaR = col.Excess_Return.filter(col.Excess_Return <= percentile_lower).mean(),
    Upper_CVaR = col.Excess_Return.filter(col.Excess_Return >= percentile_upper).mean(),
.with_columns(
    Rachev_Ratio = (col.Lower_CVaR / col.Upper_CVaR).abs(),
).with_columns(
    Rachev_Ratio = pl.when(col.Rachev_Ratio > 3).then(3).otherwise(col.Rachev_Ratio)
)[lookback_days:].drop('index')

Specifically the lines:
Lower_CVaR = col.Excess_Return.filter(col.Excess_Return <= percentile_lower).mean(),
Upper_CVaR = col.Excess_Return.filter(col.Excess_Return >= percentile_upper).mean(),`

To use filter on col.Excess_Return it needs to be called twice, first so .filter can be called and second in the condition statement itself.
There doesn't seem to be pl.filter as a shorthand.  df.filter doesn't work in this scenario, neither does pl.all.filter nor pl.all().filter or pl.col('*').filter.
Does anyone know the idiomatic way to use filter in .agg or in similar contexts?  Should the column name be written twice in every if statement?

I don't think there's something like this. It's not in the documentation either - https://docs.pola.rs/api/python/stable/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.filter.html.
You could do (lambda x: x.filter(x <= ..).mean())(col.Excess_Return), but not sure it makes it easier to read.

it would be nice to have some expression shorthand for that, similar to pl.element(). Something like pl.current() maybe.

RE: pl.element() inside .filter https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/13772#issuecomment-1948476798

Least hacky
You can use the walrus operator to keep from repeating the column directly.
Lower_CVaR = (x:=col.Excess_Return).filter(x<= percentile_lower).mean(),
Upper_CVaR = (y:=col.Excess_Return).filter(y>= percentile_upper).mean(),`

It's not ideal but it's not too hacky.
Really hacky
Here's something, let's make a Class where we'll monkey path an object into your polars namespace and call it "elem" as in pl.elem and we'll make it pl.col('terkcvzlkfgrt4598') where that name is just me mashing the keyboard. That class will have a filter method where you can use pl.elem as a placeholder and then it'll swap out the placeholder for whatever you put into the initializer of the class. Here it is:
from io import StringIO
class CF:
    def __init__(self, col_name):
        import polars as pl
        self.col=pl.col(col_name)

        if 'pl' in globals() and globals()['pl']==pl:
            global_pl='pl'
        else:
            global_keys=globals().keys()
            for k in global_keys:
                if k=="__": continue
                try:
                    if globals()[k]==pl:
                        global_pl=k
                        break
                except:
                    pass
        setattr(globals()[global_pl], 'elem', pl.col('terkcvzlkfgrt4598'))
    def filter(self, filt_expr):
        serialized = (
            filt_expr.meta.serialize()
            .replace(
                """{"Column":"terkcvzlkfgrt4598"}""", 
                self.col.meta.serialize()
                )
        )
        new_filt_expr=pl.Expr.deserialize(StringIO(serialized))
        return new_filt_expr

With that setup, you can then do
Lower_CVaR = CF('Excess_Return').filter(pl.elem<= percentile_lower).mean(),
Upper_CVaR = CF('Excess_Return').filter(pl.elem>= percentile_upper).mean(),


Very cool!  I didn't know you could use the walrus operator like that, in the middle of function arguments.  E.g. this works:
Lower_CVaR = (x:=col(calc_column)).filter(x <= percentile_lower).mean(),
Upper_CVaR = x.filter(x >= percentile_upper).mean(),
Ofc this looks hacky, but it's cool to see Python supports this.
Maybe one day Polars will officially support pl.elem.  I wonder if Python supports creating a method called this or self, so it's pl.this or pl.self instead of pl.elem.  Maybe others will disagree with me but I think that's more readable syntax.

As mentioned in the comments, at the moment there's no shortcut for that, but there's an open issue to allow usage of pl.element() inside filter() method.
If your expression is particularly complicated, you could probably use inline anonymous function to shorten it.
In your cause it might look like
Lower_CVaR = (lambda x: x.filter(x <= percentile_lower).mean())(col.Excess_Return),
Upper_CVaR = (lambda x: x.filter(x >= percentile_upper).mean())(col.Excess_Return)

It's not particularly shorter, but at least col.Excess_Return is only mentioned once which means it's a bit less error-prone.
